# Python Skype4Py message status remains 'SENDING'

Tags: python, skype4py

```
import Skype4Py

skype=Skype4Py.Skype()

skype.Client.Start()

skype.Attach()

skype.SendMessage('echo123','Test')
```

The code works, but for some reason, when I send a message, its status remains `SENDING`, therefore I am not able to send any messages.

Edit  : turns out the method sends the message as soon as the contact is online.

Comment: You should add your edit as an answer so future visitors will notice it.

Answer (score 3):

Messages are always sent when the user is online.